# Parameter value [0] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer]

Tags: java, spring, jpa, stored-procedures, hql

Fun issue where I'm passing an `int` in and it's complaining about it not matching the type:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [0] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer]`

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "dbo.do_cool_stuff_to_client")
void coolClientStuff(int clientId);
```

It's being called like so:

```
public void someOtherMethod(int clientId){
  clientRepository.coolClientStuff(clientId);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It turns out there is something stupid/funky with it, where it really wants me to put in the class type and not a primitive type.

Changing the method signature to use `Integer` instead of `int` fixed it.

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "dbo.do_cool_stuff_to_client")
void coolClientStuff(Integer clientId);
```

Comment: After reading `expected type [java.lang.Integer]` I would _expect_ the parameter to be an `Integer`. Are there other`@Procedure`cases where an int would be used in place of an Integer? I am unfamiliar with this annotation

Comment: It is pretty strange; it really shouldn't matter since autoboxing should take care of it. Perhaps when Spring uses reflection here it doesn't consider the possibility of using primitives instead of the wrapper type? It might be checking if the class of the argument is only `== Integer.class` and not considering `int.class`.

Comment: Yes, the exception made me switch it and have it work, it just was weird, cause I would have expected it to have been fine with the primitive type since that was what was being used all throughout.